# Get model data from a partial view

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm developing an intranet ASP web application using the MVC architecture and Entity Framework (Database First). My problem is the following one :

I have an entity "Person" and an entity "PhoneCard" which includes as a Foreign Key the Primary Key of "Person" (so, Id_Person). I created a CRUD controller "PersonController" using Entity Framework and Visual Studio has generated automatically the corresponding views (index, details, create, edit and delete). Then, I created an other CRUD controller (always using EF) which is named "PhoneCardController". In my Create Person view, I included the Create PhoneCard view thanks to a AJAX function:

```
function addPhoneCardCreateView() {

    $('#divCreatePhoneCard').load("@Url.Action("Create","PhoneCard")");

}
```

And call it like that :

```
<a href = "javascript:addPhoneCardCreateView()">Add a Phone card</a>
    <div id = "divCreatePhoneCard"></div>
```

By doing this, I call my partial view so I can add a phone card while I'm adding a person. Unfortunately, when I click on the Create button, it only adds the new person to the database. Here is the Create action in my PersonController :

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Id_ProductPackageCategory = new SelectList(db.ProductPackageCategories, "Id_ProductPackageCategory", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Person/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Persons.AddObject(person);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.Id_ProductPackageCategory = new SelectList(db.ProductPackageCategories, "Id_ProductPackageCategory", "Name", person.Id_ProductPackageCategory);
        return View(person);
    }
```

My Partial View :

```
@model BuSIMaterial.Models.PhoneCard

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Create</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>PhoneCard</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SimNumber)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SimNumber)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SimNumber)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PIN)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PIN)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PIN)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PIN2)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PIN2)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PIN2)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PUK)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PUK)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PUK)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PUK2)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PUK2)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PUK2)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id_Person, "Person")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("Id_Person", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id_Person)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id_PhoneSubscription, "PhoneSubscription")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("Id_PhoneSubscription", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id_PhoneSubscription)
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }

</body>
</html>
```

Person Model :

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="BuSIMaterialModel", Name="Person")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class Person : EntityObject
{
    #region Factory Method

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new Person object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id_Person">Initial value of the Id_Person property.</param>
    /// <param name="firstName">Initial value of the FirstName property.</param>
    /// <param name="lastName">Initial value of the LastName property.</param>
    /// <param name="numNat">Initial value of the NumNat property.</param>
    /// <param name="startDate">Initial value of the StartDate property.</param>
    /// <param name="upgrade">Initial value of the Upgrade property.</param>
    /// <param name="id_ProductPackageCategory">Initial value of the Id_ProductPackageCategory property.</param>
    /// <param name="houseToWorkKilometers">Initial value of the HouseToWorkKilometers property.</param>
    public static Person CreatePerson(global::System.Int64 id_Person, global::System.String firstName, global::System.String lastName, global::System.String numNat, global::System.DateTime startDate, global::System.Boolean upgrade, global::System.Int64 id_ProductPackageCategory, global::System.Decimal houseToWorkKilometers)
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.Id_Person = id_Person;
        person.FirstName = firstName;
        person.LastName = lastName;
        person.NumNat = numNat;
        person.StartDate = startDate;
        person.Upgrade = upgrade;
        person.Id_ProductPackageCategory = id_ProductPackageCategory;
        person.HouseToWorkKilometers = houseToWorkKilometers;
        return person;
    }

    #endregion
    #region Primitive Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int64 Id_Person
    {
        get
        {
            return _Id_Person;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Id_Person != value)
            {
                OnId_PersonChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("Id_Person");
                _Id_Person = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("Id_Person");
                OnId_PersonChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int64 _Id_Person;
    partial void OnId_PersonChanging(global::System.Int64 value);
    partial void OnId_PersonChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [Required]
    public global::System.String FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _FirstName;
        }
        set
        {
            OnFirstNameChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("FirstName");
            _FirstName = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            OnFirstNameChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _FirstName;
    partial void OnFirstNameChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnFirstNameChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [Required]
    public global::System.String LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return _LastName;
        }
        set
        {
            OnLastNameChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("LastName");
            _LastName = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("LastName");
            OnLastNameChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _LastName;
    partial void OnLastNameChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnLastNameChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [Required]
    public global::System.String NumNat
    {
        get
        {
            return _NumNat;
        }
        set
        {
            OnNumNatChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("NumNat");
            _NumNat = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("NumNat");
            OnNumNatChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _NumNat;
    partial void OnNumNatChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnNumNatChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.DateTime StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _StartDate;
        }
        set
        {
            OnStartDateChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("StartDate");
            _StartDate = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("StartDate");
            OnStartDateChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.DateTime _StartDate;
    partial void OnStartDateChanging(global::System.DateTime value);
    partial void OnStartDateChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public Nullable<global::System.DateTime> EndDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _EndDate;
        }
        set
        {
            OnEndDateChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("EndDate");
            _EndDate = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("EndDate");
            OnEndDateChanged();
        }
    }
    private Nullable<global::System.DateTime> _EndDate;
    partial void OnEndDateChanging(Nullable<global::System.DateTime> value);
    partial void OnEndDateChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Boolean Upgrade
    {
        get
        {
            return _Upgrade;
        }
        set
        {
            OnUpgradeChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Upgrade");
            _Upgrade = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("Upgrade");
            OnUpgradeChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.Boolean _Upgrade;
    partial void OnUpgradeChanging(global::System.Boolean value);
    partial void OnUpgradeChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [Required]
    public global::System.Int64 Id_ProductPackageCategory
    {
        get
        {
            return _Id_ProductPackageCategory;
        }
        set
        {
            OnId_ProductPackageCategoryChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Id_ProductPackageCategory");
            _Id_ProductPackageCategory = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("Id_ProductPackageCategory");
            OnId_ProductPackageCategoryChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int64 _Id_ProductPackageCategory;
    partial void OnId_ProductPackageCategoryChanging(global::System.Int64 value);
    partial void OnId_ProductPackageCategoryChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Decimal HouseToWorkKilometers
    {
        get
        {
            return _HouseToWorkKilometers;
        }
        set
        {
            OnHouseToWorkKilometersChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("HouseToWorkKilometers");
            _HouseToWorkKilometers = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("HouseToWorkKilometers");
            OnHouseToWorkKilometersChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.Decimal _HouseToWorkKilometers;
    partial void OnHouseToWorkKilometersChanging(global::System.Decimal value);
    partial void OnHouseToWorkKilometersChanged();

    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("BuSIMaterialModel", "FK_bm_Persons_bm_ProductPackageCategories", "bm_ProductPackageCategories")]
    public ProductPackageCategory ProductPackageCategory
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<ProductPackageCategory>("BuSIMaterialModel.FK_bm_Persons_bm_ProductPackageCategories", "bm_ProductPackageCategories").Value;
        }
        set
        {
            ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<ProductPackageCategory>("BuSIMaterialModel.FK_bm_Persons_bm_ProductPackageCategories", "bm_ProductPackageCategories").Value = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public EntityReference<ProductPackageCategory> ProductPackageCategoryReference
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<ProductPackageCategory>("BuSIMaterialModel.FK_bm_Persons_bm_ProductPackageCategories", "bm_ProductPackageCategories");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedReference<ProductPackageCategory>("BuSIMaterialModel.FK_bm_Persons_bm_ProductPackageCategories", "bm_ProductPackageCategories", value);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("BuSIMaterialModel", "FK_bm_PhoneCards_bm_Persons", "bm_PhoneCards")]
    public EntityCollection<PhoneCard> PhoneCards
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<PhoneCard>("BuSIMaterialModel.FK_bm_PhoneCards_bm_Persons", "bm_PhoneCards");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<PhoneCard>("BuSIMaterialModel.FK_bm_PhoneCards_bm_Persons", "bm_PhoneCards", value);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("BuSIMaterialModel", "FK_bm_ProductAllocations_bm_Persons", "bm_ProductAllocations")]
    public EntityCollection<ProductAllocation> ProductAllocations
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<ProductAllocation>("BuSIMaterialModel.FK_bm_ProductAllocations_bm_Persons", "bm_ProductAllocations");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<ProductAllocation>("BuSIMaterialModel.FK_bm_ProductAllocations_bm_Persons", "bm_ProductAllocations", value);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("BuSIMaterialModel", "FK_bm_VehicleFuelCards_bm_Persons", "bm_VehicleFuelCards")]
    public EntityCollection<VehicleFuelCard> VehicleFuelCards
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<VehicleFuelCard>("BuSIMaterialModel.FK_bm_VehicleFuelCards_bm_Persons", "bm_VehicleFuelCards");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<VehicleFuelCard>("BuSIMaterialModel.FK_bm_VehicleFuelCards_bm_Persons", "bm_VehicleFuelCards", value);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: How does the PhoneCard partial view look like?

Comment: I just posted the partial view =)

Comment: Could you show your `Person` and `PhoneCard` models?

Comment: Actually as I said, I used EF Database First so VS has generated a Model.Designer where are my models I guess... Just a minute, I'm going to post them.

Comment: It seems thats my models take too much place... I just posted the Person model, is it okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Person` model has a collection property `PhoneCards` which is always null in your Post action because you didn't respect the [`naming convention for binding to a list`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx). Also your `PhoneCard.cshtml` is not a partial view, but a full blown view (it contains `<html>` and `<body>` tags which is wrong).

I would really recommend you the [`following article`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) in which Steven Sanderson explains in details how to achieve that. It uses a custom `Html.BeginCollectionItem` helper in order to generate non sequential indexes in the names of the input fields allowing to dynamically add and remove rows.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, I'll follow it. However, I still have a question : what do you mean by "didn't respect the naming convention for binding to a list"? Because all this code was generated automatically by VS.

Comment: You may take a look at the following article: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx ASP.NET MVC uses a model binder to bind action parameters from the request. This means that the input fields you have inside your form must respect this convention. The fact that tall the code was automatically generated doesn't mean that it should work.